# How can I get my unordered list to be left-aligned?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create in-page navigation menu by styling ul & li with CSS. With the help of previous answers and a lot of trial and error, I've nearly done it - but can't get the top line to align to the left. Instead, it's indented a little bit with extra space somehow.

The real page I'm trying to update is below:

https://l-a-m.org/pages/banstead

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please?

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: disc;
  text-align: left;
  padding-inline-start: 0;
  min-width: fit-content;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  align-self: flex-end;
  color: #363535;
}

li:hover {
  color: #363535;
  border-bottom: transparent 1px !important;
}

ul.tabbies {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  justify-content(flex-start);
  align-items(stretch);
  align-self: flex-end;
  color: #363535;
}

.tabbies .active {
  color: #c70000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.tabbies li {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  list-style: none;
}

.tabbies li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  color: #363535;
}

.tabbies li:hover {
  color: #c70000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: solid #000 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabbies">
    <ul class="tabbies">
        <li><a href="https://www.l-a-m.org/pages/associate-only-rides">Rides</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="https://www.l-a-m.org/pages/banstead">Locations</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.l-a-m.org/pages/norfolk">Training Weekends</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.l-a-m.org/pages/local-observer">Observers</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
<ul class="tabbies">
    <li><a class="active" href="https://www.l-a-m.org/pages/banstead">Banstead</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.l-a-m.org/pages/tatsfield">Tatsfield</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the difference between what you want to achieve and the rendered result?

Comment: Apologies @tao, I forgot to add this link [link](https://l-a-m.org/pages/banstead)  It's an example of the in-page navigation currently used ... except it's using scss. I'm trying to achieve the same horizontal in-page nav using css, but failing miserably

Comment: SCSS is a different way of writing CSS, but it still compiles into valid CSS, because browsers only understand CSS. Use [The Sass Playground](https://www.sassmeister.com/) to translate SCSS into CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be easier than I expected with a change in the 'margin' parameter:

```
ul.tabbies {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  justify-content(flex-start);
  align-items(stretch);
  align-self: flex-end;
  color: #363535;
}
```

Changing 'margin: auto' to 'margin: 0px' was all it needed

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you're looking for something like this:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  color: #363535;
  position: relative;
}

ul li ul {
  border: 1px pink solid;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}
```

I'm guessing that you're gearing up for the sub menu to appear on hover. In that case, positioning the inner  beneath the top level nav is quite useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding class the first `ul` and using `>` to define the exact child within the parent

What is happening here is that when you enter   between two tags in css that means to apply the following style to all children are within the called tag even nested child.

Where as for `>` it only applies to the direct child.

```css
ul.main_ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  min-width: fit-content;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  color: #363535;
}

ul.main_ul > li > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main_ul">
  <li><a href="https://example.com">Rides</a>
    <ul>
      <li>Subitem 1</li>
      <li>Subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="https://example2.com">Locations</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://example3.com">Observers</a></li>
</ul>
```